# How to swipe images in the same activity?

Tags: android, image, swipe

My app presents many images so I move from one image to the flowing one through a button (i10) and to go backward I used an other button (i8).
I think this method is a bit old fashion and I want to SWIPE between images, but I have really no clue, i read many about swiping but with no success.
here is my old fashion code:

```
num = 1;
    imagename = getIntent().getExtras().getString("somekey");
    resId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(
            imagename + num, "drawable", getPackageName());
    image1.setImageResource(resId);
    num++;

    i10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                resId = getApplicationContext().getResources()
                        .getIdentifier(imagename + num, "drawable",
                                getPackageName());
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (resId > 0) {
                image1.setImageResource(resId);
                num++;
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushin, R.anim.pushout);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushinhorizontal,
                        R.anim.pushouthorizontal);
            }
        }
    });

    i8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num = num - 2;
            try {
                resId = getApplicationContext().getResources()
                        .getIdentifier(imagename + num, "drawable",
                                getPackageName());
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (resId > 0) {
                image1.setImageResource(resId);
                num++;
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushin, R.anim.pushout);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushinhorizontal,
                        R.anim.pushouthorizontal);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

You can create a pager adapter and let the viewpager handles swipe operations.

[Sample](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html)

Comment: I'm sure it will crush with the first attempt as I have more than 60 image. But I will try it

Comment: 60 images won't be downloaded at once with the viewpager. You have the control of that. If it is implemented properly, you won't have any problem